# Audio issues with a downloaded podcast

Tags: android, audio, download

I have recently developed an app to download a specific podcast.  The app downloads the audio file but the audio has little 'hiccups' every few seconds (both on a device and in the emulator).  When I downloaded the file to my computer, the 'hiccups' weren't there.  I also noticed that the file downloaded to the device is ~5mb larger than the file downloaded to my computer.

Here is my code to download the audio file:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();

int fileSize = conn.getContentLength();

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

while((count = input.read(data)) != -1)
{
    total += count;
    if((total % 512000) <= 1000)
        publishProgress((int)(total*100/fileSize));
    output.write(data);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Is there anything wrong with the code above or is this just how android downloads audio files?  Anyone else have this issue and know how to fix it?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking for a 0 byte count. Reading 0 bytes is allowable with socket-based streams to cope with network delays etc. to prevent blocking (it's why a count of -1 is considered to be EOF rather than a count of 0).

Try this...

```
while((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    // Check for count being 0 bytes read
    if (0 != count) {
        total += count;
        if((total % 512000) <= 1000)
            publishProgress((int)(total*100/fileSize));
        // Write count bytes to the output stream
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
}
```

Not sure if it'll fix it but it's good practice.

**EDIT:** Thinking about it, even better practice is to only write the actual count read by the input stream.

Comment: Your edited answer seems to have fixed the issue!  I want to test a few more downloads before I award the answer. Could you explain what exactly your edited part actually accomplishes?  What exactly is the difference between output.write(data) vs output.write(data, 0, count).  Why does this work better? Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel: It comes down to how successfully the data is being read. If your data[] is successfully being filled to its full 1024 capacity each time then it doesn't matter if you write the whole thing using write.(data). If, however, only 800 bytes (for example) are read on an attempt then the remaining 224 bytes will be from the previous stream read. Writing the exact number of bytes read (800) and ignoring the invalid 224 bytes, keeps the whole process sequential. The hiccups are likely interspersions of previously read (invalid) data.

Comment: perfect, thanks!  I am curious - if i made data[] larger (say 2048) how would that affect the download? make it faster? is it worth it?

Comment: @Daniel: Glad to help. As for optimum buffer size, think of it as a conveyor system. A guy at one end loading boxes (the server) and you have space for 1024 before moving them to the warehouse (save to output stream). A slow loader or cranky conveyor (poor network connection) means less boxes at a time (to buffer). But a fast loader/conveyor and you'll need plenty of space. So for a 10KB download, 1KB buffer is fine but for a 1MB download (with a fast loader/conveyor) that means at least 1000x the number of read/writes. A larger buffer can help but only if all/most is used for each 'read'.